# Combinatorics for Feynman Diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

When one wants to calculate the two-point-function for an electronic system with Coulomb-interactions in quantum many body systems with the path-integral-formalism

$$
\mathscr{G}_{ \alpha , \alpha^{ \prime } } ( \tau ) = - \langle \psi_{ \alpha} ( \tau ) \overline{\psi}_{ \alpha^{\prime} } ( 0 ) \rangle 
$$

which becomes

$$
\mathscr{G}_{ \alpha , \alpha^{ \prime } } ( \tau ) = \frac{ - \sum_{n \, = \, 0}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} \langle \psi_{ \alpha} ( \tau ) \overline{\psi}_{ \alpha^{\prime} } ( 0 ) \prod_{ \bullet \, = \, 1 }^n \sum_{i_{\bullet} j_{\bullet} k_{\bullet} l_{\bullet}} \int_{0}^{\hbar \beta} \mathrm{d} \tau \, \frac{V_{i_{\bullet} j_{\bullet} k_{\bullet} l_{\bullet}}}{\hbar} \, \overline{\psi}_{i_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \overline{\psi}_{j_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \psi_{k_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \psi_{k_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \rangle_0 }{ \sum_{n \, = \, 0}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} \langle \prod_{ \bullet \, = \, 1 }^n \sum_{i_{\bullet} j_{\bullet} k_{\bullet} l_{\bullet}} \int_{0}^{\hbar \beta} \mathrm{d} \tau \, \frac{V_{ i_{\bullet} j_{\bullet} k_{\bullet} l_{\bullet} }}{\hbar} \, \overline{\psi}_{i_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \overline{\psi}_{j_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \psi_{k_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \psi_{k_{\bullet} } (\tau_{\bullet}) \rangle_0 }
$$

When one then expands $\frac{1}{1 + x} \approx 1 - x$ one finds the miraculous-cancellation-scheme s.t. only those terms in the upper sum contribute, where $\psi_{\alpha}(\tau)$ and $\overline{\psi}_{\alpha^{\prime}}(0)$ have not been contracted with each other.

However... When one goes a little bit further and computes some more diagrams, one sees that the factor of $1/n!$ seems to vanish to due combinatorics reasons... I see this from a heuristic point of view (we have $n$ interaction terms labeled with indices $1 , \ldots , n$) so if one performs a contraction, one has $n!$ possibilities to do so.) This should also be fine.

My questions are:

- How many *non-equivalent* diagrams are there for each order? - Is it $2n \cdot (2n)! / n!$?
- Is there maybe some "group-theory-approach" or "graph-theory-approach" to construct these diagrams without "guessing" them, or summing over all possible combinations from the symmetric group, or at least define words like "one-particle-irreducible" without having to refer to a graphical definition, but rather a mathematical?
- Can one, as a condensed matter physicist, also use the mathematica-tool "FeynArts" in order to perform these computations? (As I scroll over feynarts.de, it seems like very based on high-energy-physics, where I have next to zero knowledge...)

Comment: I don't know the answer, and I think this question is interesting. But I know people who study the asymptotic behavior of QFT have discussed the number of diagrams at each order. This leads to the statement that the perturbation series doesn't converge, and if your "small parameter" is $\alpha$, then after $1/\alpha$ loops, the contributions start getting bigger instead of smaller (because the number of diagrams increases more than the small parameter suppresses it), and the approximation gets worse instead of better.